# Given the ratio of the sum of $n$ terms of two arithmetic progressions, find the ratio of their $m$-th terms

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

> The ratio of sum of $n$ terms of two arithmetic progressions is 
>   $$7n + 1 : 4n +27$$ 
>   Find the ratio of their $m$-th terms.

I tried everything but couldn't get the answer. Here is what I tried:-

1. $\dfrac{\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)}{\frac{n}{2}(2a +(n-1)d)}$
2. $\dfrac{2a + (n-1)d}{2a + (n-1)d}$

And $m$ terms are $a+(m-1)d$.

I tried to simplify, expand but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I cleaned-up the typesetting, but you should be clearer about what you mean. As written, each of the fractions you provided simply reduce to $1$. Presumably, the "$a$"s and "$d$"s should be different in the numerators and denominators to represent that they come from separate arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @Shaun Yes thank you.I need to learn that.

Comment: @Blue yes sir sorry I will learn mathjax now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The ratio of their $n$-th term.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114910/the-ratio-of-their-n-th-term)

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of the sum =$$\dfrac{\dfrac n2\{2a_1+(n-1)d_1\}}{\dfrac n2\{2a_2+(n-1)d_2\}}=\dfrac{a_1+\dfrac{n-1}2\cdot d_1}{a_2+\dfrac{n-1}2\cdot d_2}$$

Set $\dfrac{n-1}2=m-1\iff n=?$

We know the $m$th term is $$a_1+(m-1)d_1$$ where $a_1,d_1$ are the first term & the common difference respectively.

Comment: Sir why n-1/2 = m-1?

Comment: @RamKeswani, As we need to match with $$a_i+(m-1)d_i$$

Comment: sorry sir I dont understand can you provide the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sum a_n}{\sum b_n}=\frac{A_n}{B_n}=\frac{7n+1}{4n+27}$$
Where $A_n$ and $B_n$ are sum upto $n$ terms in the respective series. This implies 
$$A_n=kn(7n+1)\hspace{1cm} \mathrm{and}\hspace{1cm}B_n=kn(4n+27)$$
Now we can calculate $a_m$ which is equal to $$A_m-A_{m-1} = km(7m+1)-k(m-1)(7(m-1)+1)=k(14m-6)$$ and $b_m$ is
$$B_m-B_{m-1}=km(4m+27)-k(m-1)(4(m-1)+27)=k(8m+23)$$
So, $$\frac{a_m}{b_m}=\frac{14m-6}{8m+23}$$

Comment: why An = kn(7n+1) Shouldnt it just be k (7n+1)?

Comment: Because then you would have to use a different k for $A_{n-1}$

Comment: I tried using what you have suggested it gives the answer 7/135 which is incorrect. The answer I have provided does add up to the sum ratio that you have mentioned.